# Any alternative for org-git-link?

Tags: org-mode

It looks like the `org-git-link.el` is now removed from the Org mode repo. Any alternative way to link git file and commit in org-mode?

Comment: It is called `ol-git-link.el` and like all `contrib` files, it now (temporarily) lives in https://git.sr.ht/~bzg/org-contrib  - see [this email thread](https://orgmode.org/list/87pmy89fqu.fsf@gnu.org/) for details. If you are interested in the functionality, then you might want to sign up as a maintainer. I doubt there is an alternative at the moment, but who knows what the future will bring?